# Unexpected calling application:didReceiveLocalNotification: when cancelling a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

There's a switch in my app which can schedule and cancel UILocalNotification.

Which means I cancelled a UILocalNotification in **foreground** with 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:reminder];`

My app will call `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` unexpectedly.

I have no idea how it happened.

Comment: You want to cancel all local notifications?? or a specific notification??
If you want to cancel all local notifications,
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
use this code

Comment: Yes, I want to cancel a specific notification.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
Write this code in app delegate and check how many notifications are scheduled and their firedate.
application:didReceiveLocalNotification is called only when your app receives any local notification.

Comment: I found some abnormal notifications with `NSLog(@"%@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);`
But the original issue is gone magically... I didn't do anything!
I'm trying to find out.Thank you!

Comment: sounds good.If you still face any issue, just reply here and I'll try to fix that